# Number of roots of the e

Tags: calculus

[image]

I differentiated firstly and looked for extreme values then checked function value nearby that point using calculator.Graphing is not easy for all the equations too. Is there any proper method that surely tells the number of roots for an equation?

Comment: This question is about the intermediate value theorem, and you do not need to go into differentiation.

Comment: If I am correct then this function has exactly $2$ roots.

Comment: Hint:  between any two roots there has to be a point where the derivative vanishes.

Comment: @Landuros 2 roots is the answer.

Comment: @Damn1o1 Yeah, just checked again, there is a root at $x=0.01 \dots$ and $x=2.38 \dots$.

Comment: Start by considered the limits for $f$ at the end of the interval, that will rule out half the options, then plug in some values for which it is simple to calculate $f$, that should tell you the answer (using the intermediate value theorem).

Comment: @lulu always true? Is it the application of rolle's theorem? What if there are two stationary points?

Comment: For a differentiable function, yes it is always true.  Not sure what you asking about the stationary points.  It's hard, in general, to count the roots by looking at solutions to $f'(x)=0$...easy in this case though.

Comment: stationary points where derivative vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\log{x}-x+2$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$$

$$\frac{1}{x}-1=0$$

$$x=1$$

This tells us that $f(x)$ achieves maxima at $x=1$ and is strictly increasing from $(0,1)$ and strictly decreasing from $(1,\infty)$. Now just check where it approaches at $0$ and $\infty$

**EDIT:**

We can easily check that the function approaches $-\infty$ both at $0$ and $\infty$. This tells us that the function takes each value **exactly once** between $-\infty$ and $1$ in $(0,1)$ and also in $(1,\infty)$. Therefore it will take $0$ once in $(0,1)$ and then again $(1,\infty)$ which will constitute its two roots.

Comment: Can you tell me in proper way how this approaching check at $-\infty$ to $\infty$
 works intuitively?

Comment: I mean to ask how does it help in this question?

Comment: Better I add it to the answer right?

Comment: Yes you can if you want.

Comment: @Damn1o1 Added it to the question.

Comment: Oh that means it has to go down taking value zero once on 0 to 1  then going to -ve infinity touching zero again. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Damn1o1 Thanks for the tick.

Comment: You deserve it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71632/discussion-between-damn1o1-and-prog-sahil).

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\log x-x+2$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$$

$f'(x)=0$ when $x=1$.

$f_{max}(x)=f(1)=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=-\infty$ thats why $f(x)=0$ has two solutions.

Comment: Can you tell me why did we check limit at zero and infinity?